# pyspark detect change of categorical variable

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe consisting of two columns.

```
+-----------------------+-----------+
|                 Metric|Recipe_name|
+-----------------------+-----------+
|                 100.  |       A   |
|                 200.  |       A   |
|                 300.  |       A   |
|                 10.   |       A   |
|                 20.   |       A   |
|                 10.   |       B   |
|                 20.   |       B   |
|                 10.   |       A   |
|                 20.   |       A   |
|                 ..    |      ..   |
|                 ..    |      ..   |
|                 10.   |       B   |
```

The dataframe is time ordered ( you can imagine there is a increasing timestamp column ). I need to add a column 'Cycles'. There are two scenarios when I say a new cycle begins :

1. If the same recipe is running lets say recipe 'A', and the value of Metric decreases (with respect to the last row) then a new cycle begins.
2. Lets say we switch from current recipe 'A' to second recipe 'B' and switch back to recipe 'A' we say a new cycle for recipe 'A' has begun.

So in the end i would like to have a column 'Cycle' which looks like this :

```
+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|                 Metric|Recipe_name|      Cycle|
+-----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|                 100.  |       A   |       0   |
|                 200.  |       A   |       0   |
|                 300.  |       A   |       0   |
|                 10.   |       A   |       1   |
|                 20.   |       A   |       1   |
|                 10.   |       B   |       0   |
|                 20.   |       B   |       0   |
|                 10.   |       A   |       2   |
|                 20.   |       A   |       2   |
|                 ..    |      ..   |       2   |
|                 ..    |      ..   |       2   |
|                 10.   |       B   |       1   |
```

So it means recipe `A` has cycle `0` then metric decreases and cycle changes to `1`.
Then a new recipe starts `B` so it has a new cycle `0`.
Then again we get back to recipe `A` we say a new cycle begins for recipe `A` and with respect to last cycle number it has cycle `2` ( and similarly for recipe `B`).

In total there are 200 recipes.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace my order column to your ordering column. Compare your condition by using `lag` function where the `Recipe_name` column is being partitioned.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('Recipe_name').orderBy('order')

df.withColumn('Cycle', when(col('Metric') < lag('Metric', 1, 0).over(w), 1).otherwise(0)) \
  .withColumn('Cycle', sum('Cycle').over(w)) \
  .orderBy('order') \
  .show()

+------+-----------+-----+
|Metric|Recipe_name|Cycle|
+------+-----------+-----+
|   100|          A|    0|
|   200|          A|    0|
|   300|          A|    0|
|    10|          A|    1|
|    20|          A|    1|
|    10|          B|    0|
|    20|          B|    0|
|    10|          A|    2|
|    20|          A|    2|
|    10|          B|    1|
+------+-----------+-----+
```